# What is the correct way to embed Wyam into an asp.net core MVC solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wyam

What is the correct way to embed Wyam into and asp.net core MVC solution?

As the project needs advanced authentication, I've embedded it in MVC.
I am currently embedding it with an MVC controller reading generated html files with a controller and rendering it through a view.

The files are served in the following way

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return ServeMarkdownPage("index");
}

[Route("{pageName}")]
public IActionResult ServeMarkdownPage([FromRoute]string pageName)
{
     if (!System.IO.File.Exists($"HtmlOutput//{pageName}.html"))
     {
         return View("Error");
     }

     var content = System.IO.File.ReadAllText($"HtmlOutput//{pageName}.html");

     return View("MarkdownPage", new MarkdownPageViewModel { HtmlContent = content });
}
```

The view just outputs the html content into the page.

```
@Html.Raw(Model.HtmlContent)
```

Markdown generation is done with instantiation of the engine instance and transforming it into html. 
The waym recipe seems to be ignored in this case.

```
var engine = new Wyam.Core.Execution.Engine();

engine.FileSystem.InputPaths.Add(new DirectoryPath("Markdown"));
engine.FileSystem.OutputPath = new DirectoryPath("HtmlOutput");

engine.Pipelines.Add(new Pipeline(
    "DocumentationPages",
    new ReadFiles("**/*.md"),
    new FrontMatter(new Yaml()),
    new Markdown(),
    new WriteFiles(".html")));

var docsRecipe = new Docs();

docsRecipe.Apply(engine);
```

Can this be done in a better way? Is the recipe correctly invocated?

Comment: Just saw this in the docs https://wyam.io/docs/usage/embedding. `Once the engine is configured, execute it with a call to Engine.Execute(). This will start evaluation of the pipelines and any output messages will be sent to the configured trace endpoints.`

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs

https://wyam.io/docs/usage/embedding

> While Wyam is usually executed from the command line application, this is just a thin wrapper around a core library that you can include in your own applications. The core Wyam library is available on NuGet as Wyam.Core. Once you've included it in your application, you will need to create an instance of the `Wyam.Core.Execution.Engine` class.
>
> To configure the engine, you use the properties of the `Engine` class.
>   ...
>   ...
>   Once the engine is configured, execute it with a call to `Engine.Execute()`. This will start evaluation of the pipelines and any output messages will be sent to the configured trace endpoints.

So ideally since you are embedding it, you will have to manually start the process of generation.

You can create a simple helper to manage that for you.

```
public static class WyamConfiguration {
    public static void Embed(Action<Wyam.Core.Execution.Engine> configure) {
        // you will need to create an instance of the Wyam.Core.Execution.Engine class
        var engine = new Wyam.Core.Execution.Engine();
        // configure the engine
        configure(engine);
        // Once the engine is configured, execute it with a call to Engine.Execute()
        // This will start evaluation of the pipelines and any output messages will 
        // be sent to the configured trace endpoints.
        engine.Execute();
    }
}
```

And call that from your *Startup.cs*

For example

```
WyamConfiguration.Embed(engine => {
    engine.FileSystem.InputPaths.Add(new DirectoryPath("Markdown"));
    engine.FileSystem.OutputPath = new DirectoryPath("HtmlOutput");

    engine.Pipelines.Add(new Pipeline(
        "DocumentationPages",
        new ReadFiles("**/*.md"),
        new FrontMatter(new Yaml()),
        new Markdown(),
        new WriteFiles(".html")));

    var docsRecipe = new Docs();

    docsRecipe.Apply(engine);
});
```

Comment: This is basically the same as the code in the question. The issue here is, that the engine gets executed before pipelines are added, it wants to load the Razor plugin which is not available. The issue with my implementation is that it ignores the recipe, will update the question.

Answer (score 0):

Took me a few hours to get something "okish". I couldn't figure out a clean way to wire up the Razor dependencies, so I just grabbed the `contents` folder of the Wyam.Docs.Samson nuget package (razor files and other web stuff) and dumped it next to my markdown stuff

```
using System;
using Wyam.Common.IO;
using Wyam.Core.Execution;
using Wyam.Docs;

namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Wyam.Common.Tracing.Trace.AddListener(new System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
            var engine = new Engine();
            engine.Namespaces.Add("Wyam.Docs"); // or razor will complain
            engine.FileSystem.InputPaths.Add(new DirectoryPath(@"C:\temp\wyam.test\content"));
            engine.FileSystem.InputPaths.Add(new DirectoryPath(@"C:\temp\wyam.test\input"));
            engine.FileSystem.OutputPath = new DirectoryPath(@"C:\temp\wyam.test\site");
            var dr = new Docs();
            dr.Apply(engine);
            engine.Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

My project file is the following, I believe I had to edit the Wyam.Common package as it wasn't registring properly.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Wyam.Common" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Wyam.Core" Version="2.2.5" />
    <PackageReference Include="Wyam.Docs" Version="2.2.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Using this setup (VS2019) generates a site the same look as when running wyam cli with a `#recipe Docs` or whatever it is.

Edit: I guess this doesn't really answer the question, but hopefully this can be helpful in putting a solution together. I plan to use this in Azure functions where the console example is sufficient starting point.